# Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS is deprecated now what i can use?

Tags: java, android

I want to retrieve programmatically from my phone if I can install apps from the third party. Before API 17 we used Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS to retrieve this information, now what we can use? i target API > 26(oreo). I want to retrieve this information without any specific permission to ask my user. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

/**
         * @deprecated Use {@link android.provider.Settings.Secure#INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS} instead
         */
  @Deprecated
  public static final String INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS = Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS;

Comment: Thanks abnormalThinker for your quick answer. I do not understend what i need to type in my code. Can you be more explicit please?

Comment: Refer this - https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java.shtml